# Find minimum for every row in a dataframe stemming from a unique column

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, matching, minimum

I need to find the row-wise minimum in an array where each minimum must stem from a unique column.
For example, a is a dataframe/matrix

```
| X1 | X2|X3|
| 4  | 5 | 6|
| 1  | 2 | 3|
| 7  | 8 | 9|
```

When i use rowMin, the output is 4,1,7. However, what I need an output of is unique minimum of each row vs column.
Therefore the output needs to be 5,1,9
I know there are solutions in python, Im unable to do this in R!

Comment: Why not `4,2,9`?

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear, Because the matching has to be with the minimum in the column and row. So in column 1, 1 is the minimum and so it will be matched with row 2. so then column 1  and row 2 is out of the matching process, so it is then 5 in column 2, row1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use recursion as follows:

```
unique_min <- function(mat){
  if(NCOL(mat) == 1) min(mat)
  else c(min(mat[,1]), Recall(mat[-which.min(mat[,1]), -1]))
}
unique_min(df)
[1] 1 5 9
```

Note that the above is the results of doing columnwise instead of rowwise. If you do it rowwise:

```
 unique_min(t(df))
 [1] 4 2 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Another recursion

```
f <- function(n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return(which.min(df[1:n, ]))
    }
    v <- Recall(n - 1)
    c(v, which.min(replace(df[n, ], v, Inf)))
}

df[cbind(f(nrow(df)), 1:ncol(df))]
# [1] 4 2 9
```